# find the greatest sum of continuous subset, with different conditions

Tags: algorithm

I couldn't find a question relating to this specific problem I am dealing with. 
So the problem is, to find the continuous subset within an array that has the greatest sum but, the subset's first integer should be greater than its last integer in O(n) time.

For example : `2 4 12 16 3 19 5 20 18 24`

The output should be 62, (19 5 20 18).
So far I've come up with this algorithm :

```
  private int biggestSum(int[] arr)
    {
        int startingIndex = 0;
        int endingIndex = 1;
        int sum_so_far = arr[0];
        int sum_biggest = arr[0];
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < arr.Length; i++)
        {
            sum_so_far += arr[i];
            count++;
            if (sum_so_far > sum_biggest)
            {
                startingIndex = i - count;
                endingIndex = i;
                sum_biggest = sum_so_far;
            }
            if (sum_so_far < 0)
            {
                sum_so_far = 0;
                count = 0;
            }

        }
        return sum_biggest;
    }
```

I am able to get the maximum sum of a subset as well as the starting index and ending index of the subset. How can I continue? Or should I take a different approach?

Thanks.

UPDATE : As there are many people that have watched the problem and have not solved it, I would like to know if anyone can prove that this is not doable in O(n) time , although the question mentions clearly that the solution should be in O(n) time.

Comment: Are all the number in the array postive?

Comment: They don't have to be positive, for the set 2 4 12 16 3 -19 5 17 18 24 the output should be 35 (4 12 16 3).

Comment: Perhaps you could modify Kadane's algorithm to suit your condition? just guessing here.

Comment: I've thought about what you said, but if I add the line 
"if(arr[startingIndex] > arr[endingIndex]) " at each iteration then the number 2 in my example is never greater then any of the other numbers in the set, and therefore the output will be only 2. so that will be an incorrect solution.

Comment: Does it have to be `O(n)`?  `O(n log(n))` would be much easier...

Comment: It has to be O(n).

Comment: Greater or greater equal? I mean if array ends with large negative number followed by very big positive integer, will the answer only be the positive integer or it **has to** be an interval?

Comment: @farzadshbfn , The answer cannot be a single integer, as mentioned, it will contradict the requirment.

Comment: I can prove that it is impossible to find an answer for all intervals 0..k, k<=n in O(n) (it would be equivalent to sorting the array in O(n)). This rules out Kadane-like algorithms.

Comment: @n.m. go ahead, and I will mark it as a correct answer. Although I'm pretty sure that there is a solution in O(n) time.

Comment: Hold on, I'm checking the proof, looks like there's an error.

Comment: Can you add a bit of information about why you think there should be a solution in O(*n*) time? What is the source of this question?

Comment: @ruakh The source is from the Israeli Olympiad for Informatics, and all questions there can be solved in the time equvivelent to the length of the input.

Comment: @EliranZiv Can we have "negative subsets"?  I have a `O(n)` solution that can find a starting position after a beginning one.  In that case it subtracts the numbers in between.

Comment: I mean starting after an ending.  The reason for the odd behavior is that it looks for a pair of values such that one is higher than the other, and the difference between the cumulative total to that point is as large as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O(n) solution for non-negative numbers only.

Say the array is `a[0], a[1] ... a[n -1]`, where `a[i] >= 0` for `0 <= i < n` and the best answer is the subset `a[start], a[start + 1], ..., a[end]`.

We can conclude that `a[i] < a[start]` for `0 <= i < start`, otherwise `i -> end` would be better solution than `start -> end`. So the numbers on all possible start points must be ascending.

Similarly, the numbers on all possible end points must be ascending too.

Then we could find the best answer using two iterators. One iterator goes over all possible start points and the other one keeps walking until the last possible end point that satisfies the requirement `first integer should be greater than its last integer`.

c++ code:

```
int biggest_sum(const vector<int> &arr)
{
    int n = arr.size();
    // prefix sum
    vector<int> sum(n + 1);
    sum[0] = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
        sum[i] = sum[i - 1] + arr[i - 1];
    // possible start points
    vector<int> starts;
    starts.push_back(0);
    for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i)
        if (arr[i] > arr[starts.back()])
            starts.push_back(i);
    // possible end points
    vector<int> ends;
    ends.push_back(n - 1);
    for (int i = n - 2; i >= 0; --i)
        if (arr[i] < arr[ends.back()])
            ends.push_back(i);
    reverse(ends.begin(), ends.end());  
    // two iterators walking
    int answer = 0;
    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < starts.size(); ++i) {
        while (j + 1 < ends.size() && arr[ends[j + 1]] < arr[starts[i]])
            ++j;
        int start = starts[i], end = ends[j];
        if (start < end && arr[start] > arr[end] && sum[end + 1] - sum[start] > answer)
            answer = sum[end + 1] - sum[start];
    }
    return answer;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your idea. Could you please post some code or pseudocode? I'm not sure I understand how to apply it.

Comment: Thanks, great solution!

Answer (score 0):

Here is `O(n log(n))` for all numbers, including negatives.  That's a worst case, I believe that its average performance is `O(n log(log(n)))`.

We'll need an auxiliary data structure named `best_starts`.  It will store, sorted by value, information about the possible starting points of intervals.  For each point we need to know, `(position, value, running_total)` where the `position` is its position in the array, the `value` is the value there, and `running_total` is the sum of all elements before it in the array.

This can be kept in a red-black tree which will guarantee `O(log(n))` insert, deletes, and searches for nearest values.

Now here is pseudocode.

```
initialize best_starts to empty
initialize best candidate to an empty interval
running_total := 0
For each entry in the array:
    # Deal with best_starts first.
    If no equal or bigger value in best_starts:
        insert entry into best_starts
    Else:
        find next largest or equal value
        if its running_total > current running_total:
            while running_total of next largest or equal value >:
               remove next largest or equal value
            insert this (position, value, running_total)

    running_total := running_total + value

    # Now see if we have the best
    calculate running_total - running_total of next largest value
    If that difference > best candidate's total:
        record details on our new best candidate
Our best candidate is the final answer.
```

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping you'd post the idea you commented about. It would help to see actual code  (without code for the tree). I'm confused, for example among other things, by how does position play a part in the pseudocode.

Comment: @גלעדברקן The only role of position is to be tracked so that you can report on it as part of the best candidate.

Comment: where is the determination made of whether a sequence's start is greater than its end?

Comment: @גלעדברקן When we look at `running_total of next largest value` we are guaranteed to be looking at an element before us in sequence, whose value is larger than ours.  Better yet, it is the best possible candidate for an interval with us.  (The ones that are higher than that have a higher `running_total` and therefore will not produce as big a sum as that one.  The ones not in that data structure are strictly worse than the ones in it.)